# Pass multiple params to a POST - Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to pass a `team` object a `league_id` integer as parameters to my post request. But I can only seem to get the team params to pass...

Here is what I'm working with:

```
onSubmit: function () {
    axios.post('/api/v1/teams', {team: {name: this.$refs.team_name.value}, league_id: this.$route.params.id}, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }).then(response => {
      this.$router.push('/')
    }).catch(error => {
      this.$router.push('/create_team')
    })
  }
```

This is what my server receives:

```
%{"team" => %{"name" => "face"}}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
%{"team" => %{"name" => "face"}, "league_id" => 15}
```

How can I form this request with Axios?

Comment: is `this.$route.params.id` undefined inside your function?

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its because your **this.$route.params.id** is null or undefined.